# CosmosDB Zone Redundancy using Azure Libraries for Net

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk

I currently create a CosmosDB with the following properties:

```
cosmosDb = await azure.CosmosDBAccounts
                .Define(cosmosDbResource.Name)
                .WithRegion(cosmosDbResource.Region)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup(cosmosDbResource.ResourceGroup.Name)
                .WithKind(DatabaseAccountKind.GlobalDocumentDB)
                .WithStrongConsistency()
                .WithTags(cosmosDbResource.ResourceGroup.Tags)
                .CreateAsync();
```

The only place I have seen to be able to set Zone Redundancy on is the ReadReplication database, like so:

```
cosmosDb = await azure.CosmosDBAccounts
                .Define(cosmosDbResource.Name)
                .WithRegion(cosmosDbResource.Region)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup(cosmosDbResource.ResourceGroup.Name)
                .WithKind(DatabaseAccountKind.GlobalDocumentDB)
                .WithStrongConsistency()
                .WithReadReplication(Region.USEast, true)
                .WithTags(cosmosDbResource.ResourceGroup.Tags)
                .CreateAsync();
```

The problem is that I don't care about a Read Replication database. I want to set Zone Redundancy on the initial database I create. I noticed that in the Azure Portal when I create a CosmosDB manually, it gives me the option to set Zone Redundancy. Is this not possible via the Azure Libraries for NET SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify write region with Zone Redundancy do this below:

```
.WithWriteReplication(Region.USWest2, true)
```

PS: If at all possible I would recommend you use the Auto-rest generated version of this SDK. The fluent API is not generally as up to date as the Auto-rest generated API's. This gets built directly off our the Cosmos DB swagger spec and everything downstream is built upon this including ARM, PowerShell and CLI.

There is a repository with a fairly complete set of examples as well that you can use to help build your own management libraries. It also includes fluent samples but also out of date. [Cosmos DB Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-management-net)

This is the repo for the Auto-rest generated SDK. [Cosmos DB Management SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/cosmosdb/Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB)